# Creating a second page to populate posts with tag

Tags: views

I think the title is maybe a little bit confusing. Basically I want to create a page that will operate sort of similar to the front page but only populate with posts that contain a specific tag.

I already attempted this by going to `structure > views`, created a duplicate of Front Page. Then under Filter Criteria I added a new criteria of `Tags (field_tags)` and entered the tag I want to use.

When I hit save though it instead just caused my front page to lose all posts and the new page to have nothing.

Is there a way to do what I'm looking for,, I'm pretty much completely new to Drupal?

Comment: Simply start by creating a new view.

Comment: @leymannx Wow, that's super simple, I guess that's what I get for trying to be clever by duplicating a view. Thank you!